# Creating plots and then extracting data from a TIFF file

Tags: qgis, clip, extract

So I have a giant .tif file with mean tree height data over the Everglades. I have a number of 10x10 field plots in the area. 
For each plot, I have the center point and want to create a circle plot with a 5-meter radius and then clip and extract the data for the smaller plot from the larger TIFF file.

How do I go about doing this in QGIS? I used to know how to do it in ArcGIS but I can't run that on my Mac.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you have tried?

Comment: if you can recall / find the name of the ArcGIS tools you used, that'll help. There is usually a QGIS equivalent. Also, do you need to extract one tiff per plot?

Answer (score 2):

Check what coordinate reference system the point layer is in. If it's in a projected CRS that uses meters as its units, proceed to the next step. If not, re-project it into such a CRS. (Be sure to re-project it by exporting a new file. Don't change the CRS in the layer properties.)

Run the `buffer` tool on the point layer with a 5 m buffer radius. This creates your circular plots layer.

Run the `clipper` tool on the raster layer with the circular plots as the clip layer.